# Failing Cucumber Test

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cucumber

I am new to rails and cucumber and I am trying to make a cucumber scenario pass. 
Here is my write_profile.feature file:

```
Feature: Write profile
As a profile owner
I can write new profile

Scenario Outline: Write profile
  Given I am on the login page
  When I fill "<email>" as Email
  When I fill "<password>" as Password
  When I click "<btn>" button
  Then I should be on the <page_name> page
# When I click "<btn>" button
# Then I should see "Success"
Examples:
| email                | password   | btn    | page_name |
| admin@mysite.com     | secret     | Log in | profiles  |
```

and here is my profile_steps.rb

```
Given(/^I am on the login page$/) do
  visit "http://localhost:3000"
end

When /^I fill "(.*?)" as Email$/ do |email|
  @email = email
  fill_in "Email", :with => email
end
When /^I fill "(.*?)" as Password$/ do |password|
  fill_in "Password", :with => password
end
When /^I click "(.*?)" button$/ do |btn|
  click_button btn
end

Then /^I should be on the (.+?) page$/ do |page_name|
  request.request_uri.should == send("#{page_name.downcase.gsub(' ','_')}_path")
  response.should be_success
end

Then /^I should be redirected to the (.+?) page$/ do |page_name|
  request.headers['HTTP_REFERER'].should_not be_nil
  request.headers['HTTP_REFERER'].should_not == request.request_uri

  Then "I should be on the #{page_name} page"
end


Then /^I should see the "Success"/ do
  page.should have_content("Success")
end
```

and here is the output from running the tests:

```
    Using the default profile...
Feature: Write profile
  As a profile owner
  I can write new profile

  Scenario Outline: Write profile            # features/write_profile.feature:5
    Given I am on the login page             # features/step_definitions/profile_steps.rb:1
    When I fill "<email>" as Email           # features/step_definitions/profile_steps.rb:5
    When I fill "<password>" as Password     # features/step_definitions/profile_steps.rb:9
    When I click "<btn>" button              # features/step_definitions/profile_steps.rb:12
    Then I should be on the <page_name> page # features/step_definitions/profile_steps.rb:16

    #    When I click "<btn>" button
    #    Then I should see "Success"
    Examples: 
      | email               | password | btn    | page_name |
      |[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
 admin@mysite.com | secret   | Log in | profiles  |
      wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
      ./features/step_definitions/profile_steps.rb:17:in `/^I should be on the (.+?) page$/'
      features/write_profile.feature:10:in `Then I should be on the <page_name> page'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/write_profile.feature:5 # Scenario: Write profile

1 scenario (1 failed)
5 steps (1 failed, 4 passed)
0m0.137s
```

I would like to know why am I getting the error about the 0 for 1..2 arguments and also how could I make the failing test pass. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't know that this is related to the error you are see, but are the previous steps doing what you expect?  For example you are using `When I fill "<email>" as Email`.  I would expect since you have <email> nested in quotes that it will not use the example data, but instead call the step and pass the literal string "<email>" as a parameter to the step.

Comment: Yes, the previous steps do what I expect. I guess I saw this with quotes somewhere on the net and then RubyMine automatically refactored the scenario to an outline. The other steps were taken from: http://openmonkey.com/blog/2009/03/04/cucumber-steps-for-testing-page-urls-and-redirects if that helps.

Comment: Ok; in your write_profile.feature it looks like you are calling `Then I should be on the <page_name> page`, but in the error output it shows `Then I should be redirected to the <page_name> page` these appear to be out of sync.

Comment: You are right. I was trying to pass the test and I was switching the two tests you mentioned. Nevertheless the error seems the same. I edited the question to reflect the correct test. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Please also share your respective step definition code so that anyone can see the actual implementation.

Comment: I think I posted the profile_steps.rb file above. Am I missing something?